# Adobe PDF plugin for firefox takes over all inputs?

Tags: windows, firefox, adobe-reader

I'm having issues whenever I use the Adobe PDF Reader plugin for Firefox where the plugin will take over inputs outside it's "scope".

For example, if I have a pdf file open in a tab, then I can't type into the address bar for any tab on that window (different windows seem to function correctly). I have a similar issue with scrolling: when I try to scroll in another tab, it will actually scroll the pdf document instead of the active tab (again, different windows seem to function correctly). There are a few other key inputs that the plugin seems to capture and handle before firefox can.

Is there a good work-around to this issue (short of using a different plugin)? If not, are there any recommended "alternative" plugins which can be used to read pdf files? Fyi, this is for Firefox 4 on Windows 7 64bit (though firefox is 32 bits).

This is similar to this question (actually, encompasses that question), but it seems that with the latest reader more input methods are being incorrectly captured by the plugin: [Adobe Reader plugin for Firefox steals touchpad scrolling input](https://superuser.com/questions/270939/adobe-reader-plugin-for-firefox-steals-touchpad-scrolling-input)